# jQuery sortable list - disable first element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an sortable list but I would like to disable the first item, so that the input field cannot be moved.

Here is the list:

```
<ul id="sortable" class="connectedSortable">
    <input name="name1" class="inputfield" type="text" maxlength="30">
    <li>first sort item</li>
    <li>second sort item</li>
</ul>
```

And the js:

```
$("#sortable:not(:first-child)").sortable({
            connectWith : ".connectedSortable"
        });
```

I tried to solve this with the :not(:first-child) but it is not working...
Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You also can't have items inside of a `<ul>` that aren't inside of `<li>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML isn't valid, since you cannot have HTML inside a `<ul>` that isn't also inside of the `<li>`'s.

```
var _input = $("#sortable :first-child");

$('#sortable').before(_input); // move it outside of the UL
$('#sortable').sortable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nF7yW/

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    items: '> li'   
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WVqcc/2/)

Answer (score 3):

If you fix your HTML so that your input is properly wrapped in a list item, then you can try using the sortables's [items option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items):

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    items: "> li:gt(0)", 
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qfnpa/1)**